# How can I set my Google maps key in index.html dynamically in angular 2?

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm trying to set google maps key dynamically in my angular project.

Generally we set that API key in index.html file of angular project. Now I want to change that key dynamically. I'll be fetching that key by some API and the question is that how can I set that in my index.html. any help will be appreciated.

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular App</title>

  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&libraries=places,drawing&callback=initMap"></script>

  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="web_images/title_image.png">
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is Some Solution that worked for me to load `JavaScript` in Angular. It might help you..

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      scripts: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_API_KEY&libraries=places,drawing&callback=initMap').then(() => {
      console.log('Success')
    })
  }

loadScript(name: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = name;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      console.log('Script Loaded');
      resolve()
    });
  }
```

You may call api from backend to get api key in ngOnInit before loading script.

Comment: does this not still result in the script tag being visible when inspected via dev tools, thus making the key still exposed?

Comment: it does ~ you "secure" it in the google cloud console by tying it to your website.

Comment: I used the same approach but instead of doing in the main AppComponent, I wanted to load through my other map related service and there I needed to check if the maps.google... script has already been loaded or not. 
```
    if (document.querySelector('script[src*="maps.googleapis.com"]')) {
      return;
    }
```